# How to delete IE 8 cache registry through java script?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Am using the below java script code to delete the IE cache , but it is not working .
Can anyone please let us know the exact way to do it through java script.?

```
var IEDIR = "HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Shell     Folders\\Cache";
function delIECache(IEDIR) {
// Open directory name, catch "not found" error
try {
    var dir = fso.GetFolder(IEDIR);
} catch(err) { return err; }
var e;
// Delete files in the current directory

for (e = new Enumerator(dir.files); !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
            var file = e.item();
    try {       file.Delete(1); } catch (err) { }
}

    return null;
```

}

Comment: What, do you want to steal IE's cache? Bwahaha! :P

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete the IE cache using Javascript (or any website-originating interaction). being able to do so would be a tremendous security breach.

If you need the user to delete their cache, ask them to do so themselves. If you need to delete the cache for development purposes, add a META tag.